# Is it possible to put X to sleep, leaving the rest of the system awake?

Tags: xorg, power-management

Imagine a computer with two functions:

1. A fileserver and local webserver, required 24/7.
2. A graphical server for a media centre, only required when somebody is using it.

I am considering building such a machine so allow me to kick some of the disks out of my incredibly power-hungry desktop and replacing our slow 2nd-gen Atom media centre.

The problem with this build is XBMC is a power-eating beast. Left to its own devices, the CPU will never enter anything even close to a sleep state. Things have improved but the only way to be efficient is to put it in S3 sleep. Obviously this shuts down anything running. We currently wake over USB (a IR receiver).

S3 Sleep wouldn't be possible on new machine because I would want it running server things but, I'd like to put the X server (and all its clients) to sleep. If that's possible. Is it?

Failing that, I can always quit X but that would lose XBMC's state and I'd rather avoid that. If that's the only method, can you suggest a way to reinitialise X from an IR command? (And in a way that doesn't clash with XBMC's handling of IR).

<sub>**Note:** I'm completely flexible with the graphical stack. It's currently just X and `nodm` loading a standalone version of XBMC but if what you need requires something else, that's fine. I'm also able to test this ahead of building a new machine (on the current one).</sub>

Comment: `kill -[STOP|CONT] <PID>` look like they might be helpful *iff* they can work on a process tree *and* I can trigger the `CONT` signal from IR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pausing a process tree

I'm halfway there. I found `kill -STOP <PID>` which freezes a process. There's a `CONT` version too which wakes it up. Therefore I can find and `STOP` the `nodm` process tree with this sexy command:

```
pstree -p $(ps ux | awk '/nodm$/ {print $2}') | grep -oP '\d+' | xargs kill -STOP
```

And we can wake all stopped processes (for the current user) with:

```
ps ux | awk '$8 ~ /^T/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -CONT
```

This actually seems to work. I've just tested it and I'm amazed that neither X, XBMC or the file it's playing over NFS (yeah this works mid-video) seem to mind that it's being paused for five minutes.

### Resuming from IR

This was the next challenge - how could I restart these processes from IR? For this we need `irexec` which can run a arbitrary command for any button, regardless of what else is listening to lirc.

We need a few scripts in place to make this happen. First `~/.lircrc`

```
begin
prog = irexec
button = *
config = ~/.resume &
end
```

and `~/.resume` (this will need `chmod +x ~/.resume` running after it's created)

```
#!/bin/sh
ps ux | awk '$8 ~ /^T/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -CONT
```

Then all we need to do is load `irexec`. To keep it from being zombified when the STOP command is run, we have to shunt the process out of the current tree which is made simple with `setsid`. In my case, I add the following before xbmc's launcher in `~/.xsession`:

```
setsid irexec
```

### The final mystery: How can I get XBMC to run the STOP script instead of sleeping?

The only part I haven't solved now is getting XBMC to run a command instead of shutting down. Work in progress. The only option I can find at the moment is creating a custom Python screensaver for XBMC which seems *really* dull (and I can't get it working).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not xbmc specialist but if it uses Lirc to catch IR messages you could add something like this to the ~/.licrc or /etc/lirc/lircrc files to trigger your scripts.

```
  begin wakeupwait
       button = OK (of course you may prefer to use another button for that purpose) 
       prog = irexec
       config = <your wake-up script path>
       quit
  end wakeupwait

  begin
       button = OK (same button) 
       prog = irexec
       config = <your pause script path>
       mode = wakeupwait
  end
```

some documents:

irexec http://www.lirc.org/html/irexec.html

.lircrc http://www.lirc.org/html/configure.html
(mode option is worth to read)

Emmanuel

Comment: Yup, found this separately. Seems to do the job but it has to be loaded outside of the X loop (in this case) or it'll be suspended too.

Comment: one way to do that is using batch command :
echo command | batch